# Modifying ASA HTTP authentication page

Tags: networking, authentication, cisco-asa, web

The Cisco ASA has a feature where a blocked HTTP request can be redirected to a web page hosted on the ASA itself in order to allow the web user to authenticate himself to the ASA and unblock the request.  This is configured with the `aaa authentication listener http <interface> redirect` command documented in [Configuring AAA for Network Access](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa90/configuration/guide/asa_90_cli_config/access_fwaaa.html#33272).

The page that the user is redirected to is generic and ugly.  Is there any way to get that page to appear different?  Things I can imagine include a template on the ASA that can be modified, a way to embed that page inside another web page, or some sort of CSS insertion.  However, I'm open to anything.

Alternately, if anyone knows of a more configurable way to achieve the same goal of blocking network access to a web page prior to authentication, I'd be happy to consider that, too.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible on ASA but for what it's worth [it is on IOS](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_usr_auth/configuration/15-mt/sec-usr-auth-15-mt-book/sec-web-auth-proxy.html).

If your users are in Active Directory then you could consider using [Identity Firewall](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa84/configuration/guide/asa_84_cli_config/access_idfw.html) instead (and optionally still use Cut-through Proxy Authentication
for non-AD users). In this case you specify in your ACL which users can access which resources, e.g.

```
access-list identity-list1 permit ip user SAMPLE\user1 any any
```

And so when user1 logs in to her PC, she will transparently have access to anything, without the need to authenticate a second time to the ASA.